# ionic2 rc0 where to put all sass files?

Tags: ionic2

In Ionic Beta 2 we have decentralized our sass/scss files to our components.

Now in RC0 the upgrade guide by Ionic team is not their finest work, unfortunately.

This is how my app.scss looks like, it imports all our decentralised sass file:

```
@import '../+user/user-list/user-list.component';
```

Now imaging above 100 fold. What do I do to upgrade to RC0?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out imports work like before. Against Ionic RC0 Upgrade Documentation **there is no need to change any of your imports** inside your app.scss. All good.

```
@import '../+user/user-list/user-list.component';
```

Works. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need not import your scss files in ionic RC0. All you need is to create an scss file with the name you use in .ts selector.

Eg:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'registration',
    templateUrl: 'registration.html'
})
```

In this case i have to create registration.scss for scss.  Refer **36th point under Modifying your Existing Project** in https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#tab-inputconfig-7143